# asp.net session state is expiring in few seconds

Tags: asp.net, session, load-balancing

I'm dealing some issues after i authenticate in a asp.net application. My authentication is pretty standard, validate the user and redirect him to a new page.

After redirect to newpage.aspx -the session starts again.. i have no idea why.. I mention that is a load balance environment and i'm using internet explorer.

Could somebody help me to diagnose this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How and where is your session stored? Are you using a database or any other storing mechanisms like redis or couchbase?

Comment: session is stored in a sql database

Comment: And with "the session starts again" you mean, that the Session_Start event in the global.asax is raised again?

Comment: yes, exactly what is causing it?

Comment: session_start in global.asax

Answer (score 1):

Are your machine keys equal on both machines?

```
<system.web>
    <machineKey 
      validationKey="[place validation key here]"
      decryptionKey="[place decryption key here]"
      validation="SHA1" />
    <sessionState
        mode="StateServer"
        stateConnectionString="[connectionstring here]"
        cookieless="[true or false]"
        timeout="60" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: should be the same? they are not equal

Comment: They should be the same on each server. See this link for more info: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2007/11/22/ASPNET-load-balancing-and-ASPNET-state-server-(aspnet_state).aspx